# Update iSeries DATE/TIME/TIMESTAMP columns from .Net

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-4, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a .Net application using EF4 and both DB2 LUW and iSeries.

When we run a command on the DB2, we clone the original command into a new iDB2Command, copy the parameters, and run.  It all works great, until we get to `DATE` columns.  At that point the AS400 or the driver seems to fall down: it gets a parameter that says it is a `DbTypes.DateTime`, and contains a DateTime object, but the column is `DATE`.

The error returned (on LUW) is below. The AS400 (v6r1m0) returns a slightly different wording

> **`ERROR [22008] [IBM] CLI0114E Datetime field overflow. SQLSTATE=22008`**

The code looks something like this (and is totally iSeries/DB2-LUW agnostic)

```
// all generic System.Data classes, no iDB2Connection datatype.  The driver isn't even
// installed on dev/build machines at this point.  We rely on .Net reading the connection
// string from App.config to create the proper DB Driver (db2-luw or iSeries)

DbConnection c = ... get connection from somewhere...
DbCommand  cmd = c.CreateCommand();

var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
p.ParamterName = "V_XXX_XXX";
p.DbType = DbTypes.DateTime;
p.Value  = DateTime.Now;
cmd.AddParamter(p);
...
```

So...

Is there anything we are doing wrong here?  <strike>For LUW sending the parameter as a `DbTypes.DateTime` works just fine.</strike> ***EDIT:*** It worked just fine on LUW because we were sending a truncated date in local test code (eg, `Now.Date`). Normal `DateTime.Now` fails with truncation error just like on the AS400)

Also, we have complete metadata on the type, so in theory it is possible to tell, at conversion time, what `System.DbTypes` to convert to.  We are hoping that is all that needs to be done (or hacky convert-to-string stuff), rather than some  underlying issue.

** Solution **

Thanks to @mike-willis, we just check column before creating the command and do a manual truncation when required.

```
// get the db2 column type from our model metadata, because in .net it is all just DateTime
cmd.AddParamter("@MyDateColumn", FixParam( dateObject, metatdata.ColumnType);

// fix up different types of parameters.  real version does a lot more validation
public object FixParam(object value, string db2columnType) {
    if (db2columnType == "date") return ((DateTime)value).Date;
    ...
    return value;
}
```

Thanks, all you DB2 folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from the i, you can just assign from a `DATE` field to a `DateTime` field.

```
DateTime EmployeeSignedDateTime = i.Field<DateTime>("EMP_SIGNED_DATE").Add(i.Field<DateTime>("EMP_SIGNED_TIME").TimeOfDay)
```

In order to sent to the i, you can do that following:

```
p.Add("@EMPLOYEE_SIGNED_DATE", iDB2DbType.iDB2Date).Value = DateTime.Now.Date;
p.Add("@EMPLOYEE_SIGNED_TIME", iDB2DbType.iDB2Time).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss");
```

Note that I am using the `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll`.

Comment: We aren't using the iSeries DLL, so we don't have access to the `iDB2DbType` structure.  I will test it tomorrow morning at the client site, where we have access to a living breathing iSeries :D Looks promsing though.  We leave it a `DbTypes.DateTime`, but that can be changed too if necessary to `DbTypes.Date`.  Debugging time :D